# Sort Wordpress list alphabetically

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the following code in combination with ACF to list sub pages of the current page.

Can I force this to list alphabetically?

```
<?php
                    $this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID;;
                    $args=array(
                      'post_parent' => $this_page_id,
                      'post_type' => 'page',
                      'orderby' => 'the_title',
                    );
                    $my_query = null;
                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
                            <ul>
                    <?php
                      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <li><h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php $brand_name  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brand_name', true); ?>
                                <?php echo $brand_name; ?>
                                </a></h4>
                            </li>
                       <?php endwhile; } else {?>
                        <h1>Sorry we have no documentation available.</h1>
                         <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

There probably are dupes of this but the markup of the ones I have seen are different to what I have and I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the_title to title in

```
$args=array(
   'post_parent' => $this_page_id,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'orderby' => 'title ', //changed
   'order' => 'ASC', // updated
);
```

title is one of default sort parameters in WP you can see them [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: Thanks, also needed. 
                      'order'          => 'ASC'